# Single-Page-Application security

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, rest

I'm working on a Single-Page-Webapp (SPA) with angularjs (JavaScript) in the frontend and a php rest api in the backend.

I do a lot of ajax calls to the server for example to submit a new story. There the security question came up. The server needs to identify the request. Since it's an SPA only one client (the frontend) should be have the permission to do this request.

I've been googleing for days to find a way to identify the client. I saw that i could send a clientid in the header of the ajax call but that would not be secure since the frontend is in JS and all the JS code can be seen by the user.

Example:

```
$http.post("some/url", somedata, { 
   headers: {
       "ClientId":"someidforthisclient"
   } 
});
```

a hacker could look into the JS code and copy the `ClientId`. With that he could make ajax calls and the server would think this request is valid.

So my question is:

How can i identfiy the client in the server but with the guarantee that the ClientId (or a security token etc.) can not be seen by the user?

Comment: Do users need to login? If so, you could create a session on login, and read that session on the ajax call..

Comment: @Naruto yes in this example the user would be logged in, but what if a user wants to creat a new account for this call there wouldn't be a sesssion.

Comment: @YvesHendseth — They they aren't authorised to access any data beyond that needed to display the login and the registration screens.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i identfiy the client in the server but with the guarantee that the ClientId (or a security token etc.) can not be seen by the user?

You cannot. It is absolutely impossible. For all intents and purposes, as far as the server is concerned, the client application and the user of it are one entity.

You have to trust your users, not their software.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is expose the api of login and registration to the users. For any other api access, first you need to authenticate if user is logged in/active.

For authentication you can store user credential in session : 
Now user credential will be sent to the api on each request and you will be able to authenticate before processing the request.

You should at the same time encrypt user credential being saved in session so that no one can read that from browser console.